# i have the below table

Tags: sql

I have a table as below

```
Parent ID   child   child status        
1   abc active
1   adf deleted
1   afc deleted

2   tyt deleted
2   rtf deleted

3   xyz deleted
3   dfr deleted
3   rty deleted
3   tyu deleted

4   poi active
4   plm deleted
4   piu deleted
4   pkg deleted
```

I need to return the parent In which all the child columns are in deleted state.

For example in the above table I need parent 2,3 as result .

Comment: ummm what is your actual question?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select parentid
from t
group by parentid
having min(childstatus) = max(childstatus) and
       min(childstatus) = 'deleted';
```